# Update col1 for capitalising the first letter of each word in a string in col1 with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

After searching a code for capitalise the first letter of each word in a string in SQL Server I found this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] 
    (@InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index          INT
    DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

    SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
    SET @Index = 1

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
         SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
         SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                              ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                         END

         IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
         BEGIN
             IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
                 SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
         END

         SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    RETURN @OutputString
END
GO
```

but I don't now how to associate with updating code in SSMS ... something like this

```
update tabel1 
set @InputString = @OutputString
```

Comment: Is the goal to get an uppercase letter as first letter and after all blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cross apply

Cross Apply executes for Each row of outer query,so Assuming `tableyouwanttoupdate` has the string you want to capitalize ,you can pass it function and use that in your update

```
Update t1
set t1.string=b.string
from
tableyouwanttoupdate t1
cross apply
[dbo].[InitCap] (t1.string) b(string)
```

Comment: b is just some derived table

Comment: Thank you TheGameiswar for your help . but i get this error !! Invalid object name 'dbo.InitCap'

Comment: thats your  pasted above

Comment: ohh it s very simple it work correctly 'Update table1
set clo1=[dbo].[InitCap] (col1)
from
tabel1
'

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,s NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(s) VALUES
 ('this is all lower case!')
,('Here we have a sentence. And another one!')
,('This IS mIxEd!!! CoMMpletelY MixeD!');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,s
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT s AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N' ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS InParts
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
      ,s
      ,(
        STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ' ' + UPPER(LEFT(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),2,1000))
            FROM Splitted.InParts.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'')
       ) AS NewString
FROM Splitted
```

The result

```
ID  s                                           NewString
1   this is all lower case!                     This Is All Lower Case!
2   Here we have a sentence. And another one!   Here We Have A Sentence. And Another One!
3   This IS mIxEd!!! CoMMpletelY MixeD!         This Is Mixed!!! Commpletely Mixed!
```

### UPDATE

If you want to update your column this is very easy too:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,s NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(s) VALUES
 ('this is all lower case!')
,('Here we have a sentence. And another one!')
,('This IS mIxEd!!! CoMMpletelY MixeD!');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,s
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT s AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N' ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS InParts
    FROM @tbl
)
UPDATE Splitted SET s=
     (
        STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ' ' + UPPER(LEFT(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),2,1000))
            FROM Splitted.InParts.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'')
       ) 
FROM Splitted;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: GOOD solution Thank you Shnugo

Comment: @aziz, I'm glad to read this! As you are rather new here (Btw: Welcome!), please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder to use your right to vote. You've accepted one answer already. That is great! This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Acceptance and votes are the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!